# Bar ggplot with two y-axes

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm trying to plot data in a dual y-axis bar plot via ggplot...not sure what it wrong with my code here as I've checked it against many other examples. The dataframe (mun_ndvi_lst_long) is already in long format as follows:

```
mun_ndvi_lst_long <- data.frame(Municipality = c("City of Miami", "City of Miami", 
"Opa-Locka", "Opa-Locka", "Coral Gables", "Coral Gables", "South Miami", 
"South Miami", "Doral", "Doral", "Miami Beach", "Miami Beach", 
"Pinecrest", "Pinecrest", "Florida City", "Florida City", "Homestead", 
"Homestead", "Hialeah", "Hialeah", "Miami Shores", "Miami Shores"
), Variable = c(25.02, 0.181, 25.8, 0.183, 22.67, 0.275, 24.13, 
0.276, 24.57, 0.188, 23.71, 0.157, 23.36, 0.322, 23.1, 0.28, 
23.99, 0.262, 26.08, 0.163, 24.05, 0.259), Type = c("LST", "NDVI", 
"LST", "NDVI", "LST", "NDVI", "LST", "NDVI", "LST", "NDVI", "LST", 
"NDVI", "LST", "NDVI", "LST", "NDVI", "LST", "NDVI", "LST", "NDVI", 
"LST", "NDVI"))
```

Here is my code:

```
ggplot(mun_ndvi_lst_long, 
       aes(x = Municipality,
           y = Variable, 
           fill = Type)) + 
geom_col(position = "dodge") + 
scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . * 0.015, name = "NDVI")) + 
labs(y = "LST (°C)")
```

I end up with the following, where it looks like NDVI is still corresponding to the left y-axis rather than the right:

[image]

Comment: Not sure that I understand "NDVI is still corresponding to the left y-axis". The right axis is labelled as NDVI and the values on the right axis are the smaller values, corresponding to type NDVI in the data. It looks like the expected output - have I missed something?

Comment: @neilfws the right axis scale is correct, but the blue bars should correspond to the NDVI data (as the red "LST" bars correspond to LST data), however they're all virtually = zero, as if they were assigned to the left y-axis scale rather than the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to transform your `Variable` values with the inverse of the transformation in `sec_axis`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

mun_ndvi_lst_long %>%
  mutate(Variable = ifelse(Type == "NDVI", Variable / 0.015, Variable)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Municipality, y = Variable, fill = Type)) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge") + 
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . * 0.015, name = "NDVI")) + 
  labs(y = "LST (°C)")
```

[image]

However, this isn’t ideal visualization practice in most cases. I would recommend facets with separate axes instead:

```
ggplot(
  mun_ndvi_lst_long,
  aes(x = Municipality, y = Variable, fill = Type)
  ) + 
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) + 
  facet_wrap(vars(Type), ncol = 1, scales = "free") + 
  labs(y = "LST (°C)")
```

[image]